# Puedo hacer un operador or en css?

Tags: css, hover

Quiero hacer un operador `or` que me permita hacer que si `elemento:hover` o `elementodos:hover` en css, pero no se como hacerlo. Aqui está mi código:

```css
div.info {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

button:hover + .info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>Mostrar info</button>
        <div class="info">
          Pon una contraseña segura: con numeros, letras mayúsculas y     minúsculas, carácteres especiales...
        </div>
```

Pero cuando dejo de pasar el ratón por encima del botón, el `div.info` ya no se muestra, porque el botón ya no está en su estado `:hover`. Asi que mi pregunta es:

> Hay alguna manera de hacer un operador `or` (`button:hover` o `div.info` con `display: block;:hover`)?

Comment: No entiendo qué estás queriendo hacer. ¿Está mal que desaparezca el _div.info_ cuando se dejar de hacer _hover_ al botón? ¿Por qué? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: Esto tampoco entendí: "que si `elemento:hover` o `elementodos:hover` en css". ¿Faltó alguna palabra?

Comment: @padaleiana a tu primer comentario: yo quiero que al hacer `hover` en el boton, aparezca el `div.info`, pero que si se esta mostrando, cuando pase el cursor sobre el, que no desaparezca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Quieres que .info haga algo cuando el botón o el div tienen el ratón encima? Prueba esto, así harás que el display sea block cuando el ratón esté encima de button o cuando esté encima de .info:

```css
div.info {
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   display: none;
}

button:hover + .info, .info:hover { /* Dos selectores separados por coma para que el CSS se cumpla con los dos, al hacer hover en uno y/o en el otro */
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>Mostrar info</button>
<div class="info">
 Pon una contraseña segura: con numeros, letras mayúsculas y     minúsculas, carácteres especiales...
</div>
```